# Showing that the integral of a simple non-negative function is well-defined

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

I would like a confirmation whether my reasoning for the following problem is solid, as the problem seems so trivial that I'm not sure whether it really is, or am I just missing the bigger picture.

Suppose that the integral of any indicator function is defined to be $\int1_Bd\mu = \mu[B]$, and the linearity of the integral is known in a measurable space $(\Omega, F, \mu)$. Furthermore assume that for a simple non-negative function $h$ we have two representations: $h = \sum_{i=1}^na_i1_{A_i}$ and $h = \sum_{k=1}^{n'}a'_k1_{A'_k}$. We'd like to show that $\int \sum_{i=1}^na_i1_{A_i} d\mu = \int \sum_{k=1}^na'_k1_{A'_k} d\mu$.

To this end, by linearity of the integral $\int hd\mu = \sum_{i=1}^na_i\int 1_{A_i}d\mu = \sum_{i=1}^na_i\mu[A_i] = \int hd\mu = \sum_{i=1}^{n'}a'_i\int 1_{A'_i}d\mu = \sum_{i=1}^{n'}a'_i\mu[A'_i]$. Thus we are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your proof, you are assuming that $\int h \,d\mu$ is well defined, independent of the representation of $h$. But that is exactly what you are trying to prove. If you read your proof you see that you go in a circle $\int h \,d\mu = \dots = \int h \,d\mu$.

I'm not sure what you are trying to show. It doesn't make sense that you know the integral is linear, yet you don't even know that it is well defined.

Nonnegative simple functions are precisely the measurable functions whose range is a finite subset of $[0, \infty)$. Usually, the integral of a nonnegative simple function $f$ with range $f(\Omega) = \{x_1, \dots, x_n\} \subset [0, \infty)$ is defined as $\int f \,d\mu = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_i\mu(f = x_i)$. Here there are no issues of well definedness. With this definition, the main thing that needs to be proved is that $\int(f + g)\,d\mu = \int f \,d\mu + \int g\,d\mu$ and $\int cf \,d\mu = c \int f\,d\mu$ for all nonnegative simple functions $f, g$ and $c \in [0, \infty)$. After you prove these, then you are entitled to conclude that if $h = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_i1_{E_i}$ with $a_i \in [0, \infty)$, then $$\int h\,d\mu = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_i\int 1_{E_i}\,d\mu = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_i\mu(E_i).$$